# How to call the new Wordpress inline link dialog in a text field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

We are using the following JS to open the standard Wordpress link dialogue:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('#acf-field-online_lesen').on('click', function(event) {
        wpActiveEditor = true;// override  var as link dialogue expects wp_editor
        wpLink.open();// Open the link popup
    return false;
    });

$('#wp-link-submit').on('click', function(event) {
    var linkAtts = wpLink.getAttrs();// link attr (href, target) in object(wpLink.getAttrs())
    $('#acf-field-online_lesen').val(linkAtts.href);// Get href attr, add to textfield
    wpLink.textarea = $('.cmb_text_link');// fake textarea in order to close link dialogue
        wpLink.close();// Close the dialogue
        event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
        event.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    });

$('#wp-link-cancel, #wp-link-close').on('click', function(event) {
    wpLink.textarea = $('.cmb_text_link');
    wpLink.close();
    event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
    event.stopPropagation();
    return false;
    });

});
```

How can we adapt this to call the new Wordpress inline link dialog:

[image]

instead of the old one:

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: what exactly is this  link dialogue and why do you need it ?

Comment: @madalinivascu Wrong link dialog pic. Just inserted the correct one. We want to call this dalog from a text field and insert the link back into the text field.

Comment: and what's the problem?

Comment: @madalinivascu Our script calls the old WP link dialog (see above) and we need it to call the new one.